# Add middleware to all firebase functions in one line / function

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions

In `express` you can add middleware such as `app.use(cors())` which adds it to all of the endpoints, however I can't find something similar in firebase examples. [Here is the example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42755131/enabling-cors-in-cloud-functions-for-firebase#answer-50992145) (see below) of how to apply it in **every function. However I want to apply the middleware (cors or other) *globally*,** as I have many functions.

```
import * as cors from 'cors';
const corsHandler = cors({origin: true});

export const exampleFunction= functions.https.onRequest(async (request, response) => {
       corsHandler(request, response, () => { return handler(req, res) });
});
```

What is the equivalent of `app.use()` in firebase? Is [adding and express server](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/blob/master/authorized-https-endpoint/functions/index.js) the [**only** option](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49104012/firebase-functions-chain-middleware)?

Comment: Here is an official firebase functions sample that shows using express to handle the middleware. Export the express app and the function is public. https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/blob/main/authorized-https-endpoint/functions/index.js

Comment: @IcyIcicle sorry, that link is if you use an express service, not if you export the function directly. If it were to do the express service, there wouldn't be a need for this question

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**Use currying** to create a handler, you have to repeat it across all the functions, but it's easier than writing the middleware each time:

```
const applyMiddleware = handler => (req, res) => {
  return cors(req, res, () => {
    return handler(req, res)
  })
}
exports.handler = functions.https.onRequest(applyMiddleware(yourHandler))
```

**Edit, an example of a more complex middleware:**

```js
const applyMiddleware =
  (handler, { authenticatedRoute = false } = {}) =>
  (req, res) => {
    if (authenticatedRoute) {
      const isAuthorized = isAuthenticated(req)
      if (!isAuthorized) {
        return res.status(401).send('Unauthorized')
      }
    }
    return cors(req, res, () => {
      return handler(req, res)
    })
  }
exports.handler = functions.https.onRequest(
   applyMiddleware(yourHandler, { authenticatedRoute: true })
)
```

Comment: I got this error `ReferenceError: handler is not defined` and I fixed with https://gist.github.com/jrichardsz/691e6194fd0499649158bcbfd9075428#file-firebase-functions-add-cors-md

Comment: The handler is your own handler which is why it's left out actually

Comment: In the question you have ES6 with the import cors statement and export const exampleFunction. Please add these to the answer too (the answer uses exports.handler so is inconsistent with the question). Thanks! Then do we need to do anything with {origin: true} using the answer?

Comment: Following from above, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/50992145/3210158

Comment: I updated the `handler` to `yourHandler` to add clarity. this question isn't about cors functionality, just having a middleware wrapper, so I wrote it cleanly for that. The code in the question isn't that great

Answer (score 2):

```
import cors from 'cors'

const corsHandler = cors({origin: true});
const applyCORS = handler => (req, res) => {
  return corsHandler(req, res, _ => {
    return handler(req, res)
  })
}

export const firebasefunc = functions.https.onRequest(applyCORS(myhandler))
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.

Comment: I don't think this answer adds anything new beyond what the accepted answer has

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way in which you can add a middleware function to the controller itself as a one-liner. In this case, the `useMiddleware()` is the middleware line.

```js
const useMiddleware = async (
    req,
    res,
    ...funcs
) => {
    // note: runMiddlewareFunctions could use some clean up
    const runMiddlewareFunctions = async (req , res, ...funcs)  => {
        let called = false
        if (funcs.length == 0) return;

        const val = await (funcs[0](req, res, async () => {
            called = true
            await runMiddlewareFunctions(req, res, ...funcs.slice(1))
        }))
        if (!called && val == undefined) {
            await runMiddlewareFunctions(req, res, ...funcs.slice(1))
        }
    }

    runMiddlewareFunctions(req, res, ...funcs)
}

const middleware = (req, res, next) => {
   if (!req.body) return res.status(403).send('-_-');
   console.log('hi');
   next();
}

const middleware2 = async (req, res) => {
   console.log('hi2');
}

const middleware3 = (req, res) => {
   console.log("hi3");
}


functions.https.myFunction(async (request, response) => {
  useMiddleware(req, res, middleware1, middleware2, middleware3); 

  // your controller
})
```